# Pointers Pass by Reference Powered

Tags: c++

I need to create a void function that gives the powered result of the user input. I keep getting an error on line 15 that says

> expected primary expression before int

Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void powered(int* x, int y);

int main()
{
    int *numPtr;
    int power;

    cout << "Enter an integer and its power: ";
    cin >> *numPtr;
    cin >> power;
    powered(int *numPtr, &power);
    cout << "Result is " << *numPtr << endl;

    return 0;
}

void powered(int* x, int y)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= y; i++){
        *x = *x * y;
    }
}
```

This is the sample output:

```
Enter an integer and its power: 3 4

Result is 81
```

Comment: Remove the `int *` from this part: `powered(int *numPtr`

Comment: After you fix that `numPtr` is uninitialized in the code that is shown. Not sure why you are using a pointer at all.

Comment: `powered(int *numPtr, &power);` should be `powered(numPtr,power);`

Comment: Technically this isn't passing anything _by reference_.  You're just passing a pointer by value.  If you want true references, C++ has a different type for that.

Comment: Your formula for the power is wrong: `*x = *x * y;`

Answer (score 3):

There's a bug in your code

```cpp
int *numPtr;
```

This creates an uninitialized pointer object. It's not pointing to an actual `int`. So using it is undefined behavior. Don't use a pointer here.

Because we're using C++, and your question literally says "reference" in the title, you should use "pass by reference" for this. I.e.

```cpp
void powered(int& x, int y)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= y; ++i){
        x *= y;
    }
}
```

Then you can just pass

```cpp
int main()
{
    int num;
    int power;

    std::cout << "Enter an integer and its power: ";
    std::cin >> num;
    std::cin >> power;
    powered(num, power);
    std::cout << "Result is " << num << '\n';
```

Comment: Perhaps numPtr should be renamed, too ...

Comment: @Sebastian good idea!

Answer (score 2):

This is because your `powered(int* x, int y)` is expecting a pointer in first argument, and int value in second argument. Furthermore, your algorithm for calculating power has logic error. I will leave it to you. Your function call should be:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void powered(int* x, int y);

int main()
{
    int num;
    int power;

    cout << "Enter an integer and its power: ";
    cin >> num;
    cin >> power;
    powered(&num, power);
    cout << "Result is " << num << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that `&` operator extracts the pointer of `num`. Dereference operator `*` is unnecessary to your main function.